# Javascript - Convert Nested Object to Array of items

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, hierarchy

I have a object which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Electronics",
    "path": "Electronics",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Laptops & PC",
        "path": "Electronics > Laptops & PC",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Phones & Accessories",
        "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Smartphones",
            "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Android",
                "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > Android",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "iOS",
                "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > iOS",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Software",
    "path": "Software",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

And I wanted to convert it to something like this:

```
[
  {header: 'Electronics'},
  {name: 'Laptops & PC', group: 'Electronics', id: 2},
  {name: 'Phones & Accessories', group: 'Electronics', id: 7},
  {name: 'Smartphones', group: 'Phones & Accessories', id: 8},
  {name: 'Android', group: 'Smartphones', id: 9},
  {name: 'iOS', group: 'Smartphones', id: 10},
  {divider: true},
  {name: 'Software', group: 'Software', id: 11}
]
```

Basically,

- If a root element has children, it should be converted as `header`.
- All the elements should have its parent name as `group`
- When finished with one root element, It needs to insert `{divider: true}` before proceeding to the next. (If it's the last root element, do not insert `{divider: true}`

While I was able to find lots of Hierarchical to JSON solutions on stackoverflow, I was not able to reverse engineer those solutions.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by checking header keeping the corresponding divider and iterate children.

Then you need to add the standard object for any item.

The recursive callback uses a closure over the group. if not set, the group is a root item.

```js
function getParts(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(group) {
        return function ({ id, name, children }, i, { length }) {
            if (!group && children.length) {
                result.push({ header: name });
            }
            if (group || !children.length) {
                result.push({ name, group: group || name, id });
            }
            children.forEach(iter(name));
            if (!group && i + 1 !== length) {
                result.push({ divider: true });
            }
        };
    }(''));
    return result;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Electronics", path: "Electronics", children: [{ id: 2, name: "Laptops & PC", path: "Electronics > Laptops & PC", children: [] }, { id: 7, name: "Phones & Accessories", path: "Electronics > Phones & Accessories", children: [{ id: 8, name: "Smartphones", path: "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones", children: [{ id: 9, name: "Android", path: "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > Android", children: [] }, { id: 10, name: "iOS", path: "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > iOS", children: [] }] }] }] }, { id: 11, name: "Software", path: "Software", children: [] }, { id: 11, name: "Software", path: "Software", children: [] }, { id: 11, name: "Software", path: "Software", children: [] }],
    result = getParts(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Accepted as Answer since faster than other answers and simpler to understand.

Comment: Hey, your code does not add divider if there are multiple root with no children. Can you please fix it? Here's the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/x8ghbnzr/

Comment: @NinaScolz It works! thanks! Can you please explain the edit tho?

Comment: i removed the divider check and add a check for group (which is empty for root items) and if the item is not the last item with index and length.

Comment: Could you see this link guys..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039222/how-to-implement-hierarchical-multilevel-datatable-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment91031196_52039222

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach using `array.reduce` and the spread operator (`...`) to flatten lists as you move through the data, and a separate helper function to take care of non-headers:

```js
const flatten = data => 
  data.reduce((a, e, i) => {
    if (e.children.length) {
      a.push({header: e.name});
      a.push(...flattenR(e.children, e.name));
    }
    else {
      a.push({name: e.name, group: e.name, id: e.id});
    }
    
    if (i < data.length - 1) {
      a.push({divider: true});
    }
    
    return a;
  }, [])
;

const flattenR = (data, grp) => 
  data.reduce((a, e) => {
    a.push({name: e.name, group: grp, id: e.id});
    a.push(...flattenR(e.children, e.name));
    return a;
  }, [])
;

const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Electronics",
    "path": "Electronics",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Laptops & PC",
        "path": "Electronics > Laptops & PC",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Phones & Accessories",
        "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Smartphones",
            "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Android",
                "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > Android",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "iOS",
                "path": "Electronics > Phones & Accessories > Smartphones > iOS",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Software",
    "path": "Software",
    "children": []
  }
];

console.log(flatten(data));
```

Comment: Appreciate the efforts! :)